# How to make a backup of Database automatically once on clicking 'X' button of browser?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database-backups

Hope someone advise,

I have a code using PHP which is making a backup of my database on logging out of my session but I need also to make a backup once I click the 'X' button right top of the browser using JS I guess.

Also I tried to use `onunload` / `onbeforeunload` / `onclose` functions but every click in any another page in the app it making a backup but I just want the backup while closing the page.

I know it's a complicated case but It's the best way I've used to keep my database backing up automatically once I left the app.

Here is the PHP code of backing up database:

```
        $databases = ['laligacafe']; //Database name
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $host = "localhost";

        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');

        if(!file_exists("C:/xampp/htdocs/LaLigaCafe/assets/sql_backups")){
            mkdir("C:/xampp/htdocs/LaLigaCafe/assets/sql_backups");
        }

        foreach($databases as $database){
            if(!file_exists("C:/xampp/htdocs/LaLigaCafe/assets/sql_backups/$database")){
                mkdir("C:/xampp/htdocs/LaLigaCafe/assets/sql_backups/$database");
            }

            $filename = $database."_".date("F_d_Y")."@".date("g_ia").uniqid("_", false);
            $folder = "C:/xampp/htdocs/LaLigaCafe/assets/sql_backups/$database/".$filename.".sql";

            exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user={$user} --password={$pass} --host={$host} {$database} --result-file={$folder}", $output);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have an AJAX connection kept alive and updating a timestamp on a file (each user will require a different file).

When the file is older than the keepalive time, have a cron job or scheduled task run the backup and delete the file (to avoid multiple backups).

With your architecture, however, this means that if the user *logs in before the backup has completed*, however the backup may be done, strange things may happen. I'd advise you to change your architecture, or explain to us why you need such a fanciful solution.

Comment: Yesterday I lost my old data and I tried to get it back but unfortunately I have no access to my old database for a reason which is updating Xampp noticed that `ibdata1` is no longer exist in old folders of xampp so I make this case because I forgot so many times to make a backup of my database.

Comment: Oh! In that case, you might want to look into *replication* -- and even more, schedule backups using Scheduled Tasks. You could replicate the database with a secondary MySQL process running on a different port, saving read-only on different files, maybe even with a safety delay. For backups, I know there are utilities that save into successive files, so you always have the last N copies (if you only take only one copy, you risk losing data in case of power loss during the backup).